# Modo di dire per una persona pratica e realista

Tags: idioms, phrase-request

Vi chiedo su un modo di dire per esprimere che una persona ha un senso pratico e realistico delle cose. Penso che abbia sentito dire a un'italiana un'espressione con le parole "piedi" e "terra", ma adesso non la ricordo. Era qualcosa simile a "toccare con i piedi in terra". Usava questa espressione con la negazione in una frase simile a "non tocca con i piedi in terra" per esprimere giusto il contrario: una persona che ha delle idee strambe, non realistiche, non pratiche. L'ho cercato nel [Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/index.shtml), ma non l'ho trovato.

Comment: “Piedi ben piantati a terra”, forse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L['espressione](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/T/terra.php) che cerchi è:

> **Stare con i piedi per terra**, non fantasticare, pensare e agire con realismo: *non fare progetti impossibili, stai con i piedi per t.*,

in contrapposizione a ***[stare con la testa tra le nuvole](http://www.comitatolinguistico.com/it/modi-di-dire-in-italiano-avere-la-testa-fra-le-nuvole/)***, che è proprio di chi è distratto o fa progetti poco concreti.

---

Solitamente lo *stare con i piedi per terra* è associato all'*[avere la testa sulle spalle](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/T/testa.php)* (cioè all'essere «a posto, comportarsi con giudizio, in modo riflessivo») e, talvolta, all'*[essere una testa quadra](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/T/testa.php)* (ovvero essere una «persona particolarmente logica», razionale).

Comment: Interessante: in catalano diciamo "tocar de peus a terra".

Comment: @Charo dunque è molto simile alla forma italiana... :)

Comment: È la prima volta che incontro l'espressione _testa quadra_ (il dizionario Hoepli comunque riporta _testa quadra_, non _persona con la testa quadra_)

Comment: @WalterTross Sì, in effetti la forma a me nota è solo *testa quadra*, senza *persona con la*. Nella foga di scrivere ho fatto confusione, correggo subito. Grazie per la segnalazione. :)

Comment: Da dove vengo io *testa quadra* è usato in modo piuttosto negativo.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren In effetti l'accezione è duplice. Da dove vieni, per curiosità?

Comment: @mrnld, Veneto. So che da noi c'è il detto *schiena gobba testa quadra* dove avrebbe un carattere positivo ma in pratica sempre sentito per intendere cocciutaggine

Comment: @ErikvanDoren Non lo avevo mai sentito prima d'ora. Grazie. :)