# Differenze di uso tra gli aggettivi "realista" e "realistico"

Tags: word-usage, difference, adjectives

Quando ho scritto questo [post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/6823) ho avuto dubbi su quando usare l'aggettivo "realista" e quando invece l'aggettivo "realistico". Ho letto le definizioni del vocabolario Treccani, ma non sono sicura di aver capito le differenze. L'aggettivo "realista" si usa per qualificare una persona mentre "realistico" invece descrive un'idea o un modo di pensare, di esprimersi, ecc? Potresti aiutarmi a chiarire i miei dubbi?

Ecco il tipo di frasi in cui avevo avuto il dubbio su quale aggettivo usare:

> - Una persona ha un senso pratico e *realistico* delle cose (cioè, sta con i piedi per terra, come mi si è detto nella risposta all'altra domanda): ho usato "realistico" in modo adatto oppure dovrebbe essere "realista"?
> - Possiamo dire che questa persona è pratica e *realista*: dovrebbe essere "realistica" invece di "realista"?

Comment: Realista è un sostantivo, realistico è il suo aggettivo. Non capisco il tuo dubbio. http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/R/realista_1.shtml

Comment: ***Realìstico agg.***  [der. di realista2] (pl. m. -ci). – Del realismo, fondato sul realismo; proprio dei realisti, da realista: correnti filosofiche, pedagogiche, artistiche r.; pensatori, scrittori, pittori, registi r., e tesi r., metodi pedagogici r., il romanzo r. borghese dell’Ottocento, l’arte r. sovietica, il cinema r. francese. ***Nell’uso comune***, fondato sul realismo, che ha e dimostra senso concreto della realtà: mi ha fatto una r. descrizione della sua situazione finanziaria.

Comment: @Josh61: Secondo il Treccani, "realista" è anche un aggettivo. Il mio dubbio è sull'uso di questo vocabolo come aggettivo.

Comment: @Josh61: Non capisco le differenze di uso tra l'aggettivo "realista" e l'aggettivo "realistico".

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/realista2/

Comment: ***Realista*** -  ***Nell’uso comune***, chi tende a risolvere un problema, una difficoltà, basandosi soprattutto sulla realtà di fatto: non ci facciamo troppe illusioni: bisogna essere realisti.- Mi sembra un sinonimo di realistico usato nel senso comune, come da sopra.

Comment: @Josh61: Per esempio, nel post che ho citato ho scritto "una persona realista" e "ha un senso realistico delle cose", ma non so se sia corretto.

Comment: @Charo Lungi da me contraddire il dizionario Treccani, ma l'uso di realista come aggettivo non è proprio comune e scommetterei che si concentra sul significato tecnico in filosofia (in *bisogna essere realisti*  realisti è sostantivo)

Comment: @DenisNardin: Quindi dovrei scrivere "una persona realistica"?

Comment: Uhm onestamente entrambe le frasi mi suonano strane. Io direi (per l'appunto) *una persona con i piedi per terra* o *una persona pratica, senza illusioni*. Detto questo ho appena trovato questo articolo della Treccani che sembra contraddirmi http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_386.html, per cui lascio che sia qualcuno più esperto di me a scrivere una risposta.

Comment: Nell'uso anche sinonimi, ma direi che 'realistico' si usa in modo più appropriato per rappresentazioni (idee, proposizioni, illustrazioni, storie, ipotesi, ecc.) della realtà, per evidenziare che la rappresentazione rappresenta la realtà con esattezza, dettaglio, completezza, ecc.; 'realista' qualifica  comportamenti (o anche attitudini, intenzioni, profili caratteriali, strategie) fondati su considerazioni precise, senza illusioni e speranze vane, di quel che può accadere Così un progetto realista si giustifica grazie a una descrizione realistica (io capirei anche l'inverso, ma meno corretto)

Answer (score 3):

Mi sembra che i due aggettivi abbiano significati molto diversi anche se entrambi legati al concetto di realtà e di realismo.

**Realista** indica qualcosa che appartiene alla corrente filosofica, artistica, letteraria del realismo, oppure un modo di affrontare e valutare problemi, situazioni, eventi; si usa principalmente per le persone, ma in alcuni casi anche per cose:

- Nella prima accezione può riferirsi ai prodotti del lavoro o dell'arte di una persona: *pensiero realista*, *filosofia realista*, *romanzo realista*, *quadro realista* (e non realistico), anche *film neorealista*.
- Nella seconda accezione si usa spesso in contrapposizione a *ottimista* e *pessimista* e può riferirsi anche alle proprietà di una persona realista: *carattere realista*, *atteggiamento realista*.

**Realistico** invece indica qualcosa di molto simile, prossimo, corrispondente o assimilabile alla realtà e si riferisce soprattutto alle rappresentazioni e alle cose che le contengono: dipinti ('quadri'), disegni, immagini in generale, racconti (di fatti immaginari o pretesi reali), stime, previsioni, etc.

Quando l'aggettivo *realistico* si riferisce a pensieri o atteggiamenti viene spesso utilizzato come se il suo significato fosse legato a quello di *realista* nella seconda accezione, ma non ne possiede le stesse connotazioni morali. È accompagnato in questo uso dagli aggettivi *ottimistico* e *pessimistico* (riferiti a stime e aspettative) che non hanno le stesse connotazioni di *ottimista* e *pessimista*.

Curiosamente, come nota [l'articolo trovato da @DenisNardin](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_386.html), si usa *realistico* anche riferito a persone (caso in cui, in realtà, non avrebbe senso), soprattutto in esortazioni («Sii realistico!») ma non ho mai sentito fare lo stesso con *ottimistico* (nessuno dice ”sii più ottimistico", e credo che una frase del genere sembrerebbe sbagliata a chiunque).

Per riassumere: un *quadro realista* è l'opera di un pittore realista; un *quadro realistico* è una rappresentazione fedele del suo soggetto. *«Il tuo racconto non è realistico!»* (e non realista); *«È una stima molto realistica»*; *«Non sono né ottimista, né pessimista: sono realista!»* (e non realistico).

Sorprendentemente non sono affatto appoggiato dal Treccani, che definisce *realistico* come derivato di *realista*. Questo però non corrisponde all'uso comune, e a dire il vero in molti degli esempi forniti dal Treccani sarebbe più appropriato usare *realista* invece che *realistico*.

La mia opinione sembra invece supportata dal [dizionario Garzanti](http://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=realistico) (**realistico:** *che riproduce fedelmente la realtà; fondato sui fatti, sulla concretezza; che riguarda il realismo filosofico, letterario e artistico*). A riprova della probabile mancanza del Treccani, [l'articolo](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_386.html) pubblicato sul loro sito cita il Garzanti e sembra in contraddizione con il loro stesso dizionario.

Answer (score 1):

Secondo la mia insegnante d'italiano e come spiega [questo articolo della Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_386.html)

> Riferendosi a persone, occorre usare l'aggettivo *realista* («chi considera la realtà nella sua concretezza e agisce basandosi soprattutto sull’esperienza pratica, senza cedere a idealismi o illusioni», *Grande Dizionario di Italiano Garzanti*, s. v. *realista*<sup>1</sup>).

di solito bisogna usare l'aggettivo "realista" se si sta qualificando una persona con il significato di "pratico e con i piedi per terra":

> È una persona ***realista***.

"Realistico" in genere non si deve usare per le persone, ma per "oggetti":

> *Realistico* («fondato sui fatti, sulla concretezza», *Grande Dizionario di Italiano Garzanti*, s. v. *realistico*) di norma non si riferisce a persone [...], anche se nell'italiano parlato meno controllato spesso ciò avviene, probabilmente a partire da una sovraestensione analogica motivata da costrutti impersonali come *(non) è realistico* seguiti da proposizione soggettiva:  *è realistico accettare queste proposte* > chi “accetta queste proposte” è un soggetto animato (persona o gruppo di persone) > *siamo realistici e accettiamo queste proposte*.

Per esempio, possiamo dire (esempi tratti dall'articolo sopra menzionato):

> - Un atteggiamento ***realistico***.
> - Un comportamento ***realistico***.
> - Un programma ***realistico***.
> - Una politica ***realistica***.

Questa è la differenza di uso tra questi due aggettivi quando hanno il significato di qualcosa di "pratico e con i piedi per terra", che è a quello a cui si riferisce la domanda.

Una cosa simile accade con gli aggettivi "ottimista" e "ottimistico".

Comment: Quindi un quadro realistico è pratico e ha i piedi per terra?

Comment: No, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: la risposta non dice questo. "Realistico" può avere altri significati. Grazie, però: mi sono accorta, dopo tanti anni, che il fatto di dovere fare clic sul link per leggere l'altra domanda forse complicava la comprensione di quello che stavo chiedendo qui.

Comment: Io credo che la differenza dei due termini stia nel significato, non nel fatto che uno si usa per le persone e l'altro per le cose. Posso dire a una persona "sii realistico", che è diverso dal dirgli "sii realista". Il commento voleva stuzzicare, è chiaro che un quadro non è pratico (beh, se è piccolo...) e non ha i piedi per terra (beh, se è montato su un trespolo...).

Answer (score 0):

Buonasera Charo,

### Parte 1

per quanto riguarda il termine ***realistico***  esso è un aggettivo:

> Del realismo, fondato sul realismo; proprio dei realisti, da realista:
>   *correnti filosofiche, pedagogiche, artistiche r.; pensatori, scrittori, pittori, registi r., e tesi r., metodi pedagogici r., il
>   romanzo r. borghese dell’Ottocento, l’arte r. sovietica, il cinema r.
>   francese*. Nell’uso com., fondato sul realismo, che ha e dimostra
>   senso concreto della realtà: *mi ha fatto una r. descrizione della sua
>   situazione finanziaria*. [*vedi realistico su treccani.it*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/realistico/)

derivato di ***realista*** (sostantivo maschile e femminile e aggettivo):

> Seguace del realismo in filosofia, in pedagogia, in letteratura e in
>   arte, in politica: *le dispute tra realisti e nominalisti; come agg.:
>   un romanziere, un pittore, un regista, un politico r.; la narrativa r.
>   dell’Ottocento; il cinema o un film realista*. Nell’uso com., chi
>   tende a risolvere un problema, una difficoltà, basandosi soprattutto
>   sulla realtà di fatto: *non ci facciamo troppe illusioni: bisogna
>   essere realisti*. [*vedi realista su treccani.it*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/realista2/)

a sua volta derivato di ***reale*** (aggettivo):

> Che è, che esiste veramente, effettivamente e concretamente
>   (contrapp., nell’uso com. e generico, a immaginario, illusorio e anche
>   a apparente, ideale, possibile): *le mie affermazioni sono basate su
>   fatti r.; i suoi non sono mali r.!; portami delle prove r. e ti
>   crederò; lo conosco poco, e non so quali siano le sue r. capacità; fa
>   il coraggioso, ma non so come si comporterebbe in caso di r. pericolo;
>   sostantivato al masch., il reale, ciò che è reale, la realtà dei
>   fatti: fra l’ideale e il reale c’è un abisso; non fare tanti sogni,
>   attieniti al reale!* Usi e sign. scient. e tecn... [*vedi reale su treccani.it*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/reale2/)

### Parte 2

Adesso passiamo invece ad analizzare il termine ***realista*** (sostantivo maschile e femminile) inteso però in un' accezione completamente diversa da quella precedentemente analizzata ovvero:

> Del partito del re; sostenitore, fautore dei diritti di un determinato
>   sovrano, in un momento in cui tali diritti non sono riconosciuti (per
>   es., in Inghilterra, i seguaci degli Stuart durante la repubblica di
>   Cromwell; in Francia, i seguaci dei Borboni durante la Rivoluzione e
>   il periodo napoleonico); essere più r. del re, frase dello statista e
>   storico francese A. Thiers a proposito di legittimisti intransigenti
>   durante la Restaurazione, usata spesso a proposito di chi è osservante
>   e rigoroso più del giusto, di chi difende un diritto o una teoria con
>   più accanimento delle persone direttamente interessate. [*vedi REALISTA su treccani.it*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/realista1/)

In questo caso il termina realista è derivato di ***reale*** (aggettivo), ma inteso con un'accezione diversa da quella vista precedentemente ovvero:

> Di re, del re o dei re: famiglia, casa, stirpe, ceppo r.; sangue r.;
>   Maestà r.; Altezza r., titolo che si dà ai principi di sangue reale;
>   decreto, discorso r.; palazzo, appartamento r.; marcia r.; guardia r.;
>   stemma r.; corona, manto r., ecc.; galea r., nelle antiche marine, la
>   galea destinata al servizio personale del monarca; nella moderna
>   marina militare italiana si chiamava yacht r. la nave destinata ai
>   viaggi di rappresentanza del re... [*vedi REALE su treccani.it*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/reale1/)

Comment: Tutto questo l'ho già letto nel Treccani: il dubbio rimane lo stesso.

Comment: realista può essere usato come aggettivo oltre che come un sostantivo. Utilizzato come aggettivo è un sinonimo di realistico

Comment: Penso che un buon punto di partenza per scrivere una risposta possa essere l'articolo della Treccani che ha trovato @DenisNardin: non capisco del tutto bene quello che spiega questo articolo. Significa che in un contesto formale devo usare l'aggettivo "realista" per riferimi a una persona e "realistico" invece per descrivere un comportamento, un'idea, un modo di pensare o di esprimersi, ecc, ma in un contesto più informale nel parlato è frequente usare "realistico" per tutto? Mi riferisco agli aggettivi che derivano da "realtà", non a quello che deriva da "re".

Answer (score 0):

Bella domanda. Ci ho pensato su e cercherò di spiegare quello che ho notato nell'uso comune. Realistico si usa per descrivere le "cose": un disegno realistico, un progetto realistico, una pianta realistica (una pianta di plastica) etc.
Invece le persone possono essere realiste (così come ottimiste e pessimiste). 
Realismo: è un modo di vedere la vita basandosi su fatti reali e concreti. Il realista ragiona pensando a ciò che può realmente accadere, per esempio, in una giornata piovosa l'ottimista dirà che domani ci sarà sicuramente il sole, mentre il realista penserà, che possa essere vero, ma siccome siamo a Marzo (mese pazzerello) l'ombrello se lo porta dietro comunque.
In poche parole: realista è chi pensa con concretezza. 
Nell'italiano parlato si sente avvolte "realistico" riferito alle persone (ad esempio: "sii realistico"), ma è una sovraestensione analogica motivata da costrutti impersonali seguiti da proposizione aggettiva, ad esempio: siamo realistici e accettiamo questa proposta. 
Definire una persona "(un uomo) realistico" suona molto strano in quanto "realistico" è usato solitamente per gli oggetti. Ma se usi "realistico" per definire i pensieri o dei comportamenti umani, nella lingua parlata può passare. Non ho nessuna fonte da citare, ho soltanto quello che ho notato imparando la lingua.

Comment: C'è questa fonte http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_386.html che puoi usare.

Comment: @Charo - mi sembra che nell'estratto ci sia la risposta. Potremmo fare altre considerazioni che rimarrebbero comunque  opinioni personali.

Comment: Perché «se usi "realistico" per definire i pensieri o dei comportamenti umani, nella lingua parlata può passare»? Non è l'aggettivo adatto anche nello scritto? Nell'articolo della Treccani appaiono "*atteggiamenti, comportamenti realistici*" e anche la frase "*è realistico accettare queste proposte*".

Comment: @Josh61: Quale estratto?

Comment: @Charo - "anche se ***nell'italiano parlato meno controllato*** spesso ciò avviene".

Comment: Grazie @charo. Ecco dove avevo letto che si poteva usare.

Answer (score -2):

Una possibile spiegazione, alternativa e più semantica, è la seguente:

*realista* definisce qualcosa o qualcuno che vuole, che mira, che è interessato al realismo

*realistico* è qualcosa o qualcuno che ha raggiunto l'obiettivo di cui sopra.

Aggiunta:

Il suffisso -ista spesso denota una persona che è specialmente legata a un certo argomento: *dentista* è colui che si interessa ai denti, autista colui che lavora con le auto; l'artista si occupa (ama, e cerca di creare,) l'arte.

Il suffisso -istico può denotare derivazione, partecipazione o vicinanza: turistico è qualcosa legato al (o deriva dal) turismo, per esempio. Pare brutto definire un essere umano come "derivato da qualcosa", e ciò può spiegare perchè questo tipo di aggettivo non è molto adatto per una persona.

A questa pagina si trovano alcune spiegazioni ed esempi: http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/ista-e-istico_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/

Prendendo spunto da alcuni esempi del link qui sopra, si può immaginare:

Artistico: che mostra l'arte, che appartiene o è il risultato dell'arte, "Un edificio artistico"
Calcistico: che appartiene al mondo del calcio, "Questo gergo è calcistico"
Favolistico: che esprime una favola, "Il tuo obiettivo è favolistico" (non "favolista")

Detto questo si può anche pensare che...

Realistico: che mostra/appartiene/esprime la realtà, è ottenuto grazie al realismo, è
prodotto tramite un ragionamento realista, il quale cerca la realtà, e, presumibilmente,
il ragionamento ha prodotto qualche cosa di realistico, cioé che si avvicina alla realtà.

Si può dire a una persona "sii realista", intendendo con ciò "fa' ragionamenti da realista", "considera la realtà". Le si può anche dire "sii realistico", intendendo dire "attieniti alla realtà", passa dal mondo del ragionamento a quello della realtà, ottieni il risultato corretto aderente alla realtà.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Non capisco cosa vuoi dire con "ha raggiunto l'obiettivo di cui sopra".

Comment: Volevo dire che è vicino alla realtà, che ha raggiunto l'obiettivo di avvicinarsi alla realtà. Una persona realista cerca di vedere la realtà, una quadro realista cerca di mostrarla; un quadro realistico la fa vedere "abbastanza", una stima realistica si avvicina (alla realtà), una stima reale rappresenta la realtà (ma non credo che si usi dire "stima reale").